# Insert React code in Play view

Tags: scala, reactjs, playframework

I have this view in Play:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("js/index.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <div id="hello"></div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react", "react.js"))'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.js"))'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("js/Dummy.js")'></script>

}
```

Within it, I am trying to use the file`assets/js/Dummy.jsx` which has this content:

```
React.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

For compiling JSX, I am placing this in `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.ddispaltro" % "sbt-reactjs" % "0.5.2")
```

However, the React code has no effect and page remains as it was previously.
Why is this happening?

Comment: I'd reorder the lines to the following order - 1st: the `div` line, 2nd: the React `script` line, and 3rd: the `Dummy.js` `script` line. I'd include any JS error that you see in the JS console if you're still experiencing issues.

Comment: If I reorder the lines, the outcome will be the same, because I am using `defer`.  I get no JavaScript errors.

Comment: If you remove `defer`, what error in JS console do you see?

Comment: If I remove `defer` I don't get any errors in the Play server console. I don't know what you mean by JS console.

Comment: On Chrome, Hamburger (the three lines) > More Tools > Developer Tools. There you can see a tab titled "Console." Reload the page then you should see some errors.

Comment: `Dummy.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Dummy.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

Comment: The `$` is jQuery, you'll need to include it. The `React` - you need to remove the `defer` and make sure the `React` line is before the `Dummy.js` line.

Comment: Regarding jQuery, I already added `libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "3.0.0-alpha1"` to my `plugins.sbt` file. Is this not the correct way of including jQuery?

Comment: You'll need this in the HTML also: `<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.js"))'></script>`

Comment: I added that as well, but the error persists.

Comment: Can you put in your question the full, re-ordered, without `defer`, code? Plus the full JS console log.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the JQuerry error was originating from another file.